# SyntaxHighlighter in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-highlighting, textmeshpro

Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class syntaxHighlter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField inputField;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI outputField;
    string highlightedText;

    private void Start()
    {
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnInputValueChanged);
    }

    private IEnumerator UpdateOutputField(string text)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f); // delay for 0.1 seconds
        outputField.text = text;
    }

    private void OnInputValueChanged(string text)
    {
        highlightedText = text.Replace("for", "<color=blue>for</color>")
            .Replace("int", "<color=green>int</color>")
            .Replace("float", "<color=green>float</color>")
            .Replace("bool", "<color=green>bool</color>")
            .Replace("void", "<color=green>void</color>");
        Debug.Log(highlightedText);
        
        StartCoroutine(UpdateOutputField(highlightedText));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make syntaxHighliter in TMP input field, I want for example if I type the word "mov" it immediatly changes color to blue, but here apparently the outputfield.text is not changing when I modify it here. I tried changing directly inputfield but that created an infinite loop, tried modifying input field resulted in an infinite loop

Comment: What happens if you remove the listener, change the value, then add the listener back?

Comment: @RetiredNinja no need, there is [`SetTextWithoutNotify`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_SetTextWithoutNotify_System_String_)

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing would end up in an infinite loop of updates

- a) because changing the `text` property again will invoke `onValueChanged`

  -> You rather want to use [`SetTextWithoutNotify`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_SetTextWithoutNotify_System_String_) here in order to not again invoke the `onValueChanged`
- and b) because `<color=green>int</color>` also contains `int` and will with the next run result in `<color=green><color=green>int</color></color>` etc

-> you rather want to replace `int` only if it hasn't already been replaced before (=> wrapped in `<color=green>` and `</color>`).

So this should be fine

```
private void OnInputValueChanged(string text)
{
    text = text.Replace(" for ", "<color=blue>for</color>")
        .Replace(" int ", "<color=green>int</color>")
        .Replace(" float ", "<color=green>float</color>")
        .Replace(" bool ", "<color=green>bool</color>")
        .Replace(" void ", "<color=green>void</color>");

    Debug.Log(text);
    
    inputField.SetTextWithoutNotify(text);
}
```

There are also a couple of edge cases of course like e.g. having `int` as part of a member/variable etc name.

It might be more efficient and easier to rather go for [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-string)) using e.g.

```
using System.Text.Regularxpressions;

...

const string pattern = @"(?<!<color=green>|[a-zA-Z0-9])(int|void|float|bool)(?!<\/color>|[a-zA-Z0-9])";
const string replacement = "<color=green>$1</color>";

...

inputField.SetTextWithoutNotify(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement));
```

see [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E0xgbT) for demo and see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FQAGYU/2) for further explanation how this regex works - here in short and simple

- `(int|void|float|bool)` are the keywords you want to match. This is also the first and only **Match Group**
- `$1` later re-uses whatever was the actual content in this first match group
- `(?<!<color=green>|[a-zA-Z0-9])` this weird construct is a **Negative Look-Behind**. In simple it just means only match keywords if they do not come right after `<color=green>` or any alpha-numeric character
- `(?!<\/color>|[a-zA-Z0-9])` similar to above but a **Negative Look-Ahead**. In simple again only match keywords that are not followed by either `</color>` or any alpha-numeric character

Comment: this works but there is a bug, the caret position doesnt change when for example i type "int (caretPostion)" when its replaced it becomes "<col(caretPostion)or=green>int<\/color>" , the tag is invisible and changes the color of its content but somehow the caret points inside it

Comment: have you tried setting the [`caretPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_caretPosition) then? I wouldn't claim that's a bug ... that's a new issue to tackle ;)

Comment: yes i tried setting the caretPostion+some constant , when i did that for some reason the replace doesnt work

Comment: update:it replaces the int but i cant move the caret further thant the end of "int"